# SQL I want to figure out how to get sales 10 days for each product and within each group

Tags: sql-server, group-by, data-analysis

I have a SQL Server table T1 that has orders by product_id, brand, and size for each day.

**T1:**

```
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
| product_id | Brand | Size |   Date   | Orders |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
|          1 |     1 | 11   | 10/18/18 |      1 |
|          1 |     1 | 6    | 10/18/18 |      2 |
|          1 |     1 | 10   | 10/18/18 |      1 |
|          1 |     1 | 7    | 10/18/18 |      3 |
|          1 |     1 | 8.5  | 10/18/18 |      5 |
|          1 |     1 | 9.5  | 10/18/18 |      2 |
|          2 |     1 | 8    | 10/19/18 |      3 |
|          2 |     1 | 7    | 10/19/18 |      6 |
|          2 |     1 | 9    | 10/19/18 |      2 |
|          3 |     2 | 5    | 10/19/18 |     23 |
|          3 |     2 | 6    | 10/19/18 |      6 |
|          3 |     2 | 10   | 10/19/18 |      7 |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
```

I also have a table, T2, that has the launch date for each product_id. A product_id may have more than one launch dates, signifying it is "restocked".

**T2:**

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | launch_date |
+------------+-------------+
|          1 | 8/18/18     |
|          1 | 10/18/18    |
|          2 | 10/18/18    |
|          3 | 4/18/18     |
+------------+-------------+
```

My goal is to create a table that is just the first 10 days of orders in each launch date (for each product_id, brand, and size). So if launch date for product 1 is 8/18/18 and 10/18/18, then I want the daily orders from 8/18/18 to 8/28/18, and from 10/18/18 to 10/28/18.

How would I go about creating this table?

Example output:

```
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
| product_id | Brand | Size |   Date   | Orders |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/18/18 |      1 |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/18/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/18/18 |      1 |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/18/18 |      3 |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/18/18 |      5 |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/18/18 |      2 |
| …          |       |      |          |        |
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/22/18 |      4 |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/22/18 |      6 |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/22/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/22/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/22/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/22/18 |      5 |
| …          |       |      |          |        |
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/28/18 |      7 |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/28/18 |      4 |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/28/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/28/18 |      2 |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/28/18 |      8 |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/28/18 |      7 |
| …          |       |      |          |        |
| 2          |     1 | 8    | 10/19/18 |      3 |
| 2          |     1 | 7    | 10/19/18 |      6 |
| 2          |     1 | 9    | 10/19/18 |      2 |
| 3          |     2 | 5    | 10/19/18 |     23 |
| 3          |     2 | 6    | 10/19/18 |      6 |
| 3          |     2 | 10   | 10/19/18 |      7 |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+
```

Thank you!

---

EDIT: including what I have tried so far:

My thought process is to try to create to join the launch_date and then create a column that is the number of days between the launch date and the Date of order. Then I can just filter for WHERE that column is less than or equal to 10.

This is the query I am using:

```
with temp as (
        select
            t1.product_id, t1.brand, t1.size, t1.date, t1.orders, t2.launch_date
        from t1
        left join t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id and t1.order_date = t2.order_date 
        )


    select product_id,
           brand,
           size,
           size,
           date,
           orders,
           launch_date
        from temp
        ;
```

In order for my reasoning to work, I would need to forward-fill the launch_date wherever it is null. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Here is the output I have so far:

```
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| product_id | Brand | Size |   Date   | Orders | launch_date |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/18/18 |      1 | 10/18/18    |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/18/18 |      2 | 10/18/18    |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/18/18 |      1 | 10/18/18    |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/18/18 |      3 | 10/18/18    |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/18/18 |      5 | 10/18/18    |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/18/18 |      2 | 10/18/18    |
| …          |       |      |          |        |             |
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/22/18 |      4 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/22/18 |      6 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/22/18 |      2 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/22/18 |      2 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/22/18 |      2 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/22/18 |      5 | NULL        |
| …          |       |      |          |        |             |
| 1          |     1 | 11   | 10/28/18 |      7 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 6    | 10/28/18 |      4 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 10   | 10/28/18 |      2 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 7    | 10/28/18 |      2 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 8.5  | 10/28/18 |      8 | NULL        |
| 1          |     1 | 9.5  | 10/28/18 |      7 | NULL        |
| …          |       |      |          |        |             |
| 2          |     1 | 8    | 10/19/18 |      3 | 10/18/18    |
| 2          |     1 | 7    | 10/19/18 |      6 | 10/18/18    |
| 2          |     1 | 9    | 10/19/18 |      2 | 10/18/18    |
| 3          |     2 | 5    | 10/19/18 |     23 | 10/18/18    |
| 3          |     2 | 6    | 10/19/18 |      6 | 10/18/18    |
| 3          |     2 | 10   | 10/19/18 |      7 | 10/18/18    |
+------------+-------+------+----------+--------+-------------+
```

If I can forward-fill the launch_date wherever it is NULL to be the most recent launch_date of that product_id, then I would be able to create a column to subtract the dates.

Comment: Are you planning to populate your 3rd table by schedule, or real time when an order is made? Also, what happens if there is an order on 10/20/18? Will we see 1 or 2 records in the 3rd table?

Comment: Please let us know what you have attempted so far?

Comment: @iVad Edited to include what I have attempted! and thebernardlim I am planning to populate by schedule (in batch). If there is an order on 10/20/18, then there will be one record for the product_id and size combo.